# React onChange not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, redux, onclick

I'm trying to create a products component that get's all the products available on the website and displays each of them in sort of like a box and when the user clicks that box they get redirected to that product page. I'm using react and redux and I'm having a difficulty with onClick. This is how my code looks

```
class Products extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            products: [...Some array]
    };

}
handleProductRedirect(productNumber){
    console.log(productNumber)
    // Redux function
    // this.props.handleRedirect(productNumber)
}
render(){
    var products = this.state.products
    return (
        <div id="content">
                {product &&
                    <div id="searchContent">
                        {product.map(element => <Item element={element} 
                                                    handleProductRedirect={this.handleProductRedirect.bind(this)}
                                                    key={element['productNumber']}/>)}
                    </div>
                }
            </div>


        </div>
    )
}
};

class Item extends Component{
    render(){
        var element = this.props.element;
        return (
            <div id="itemBox" onClick={this.props.handleProductRedirect(element['productNumber'])}>
                <h3>{elementTitle.slice(0, 85)}</h3>
                <p>{element.Manufacturer}</p>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

so the component gets the products from an api and once it's get them it iterates through them. However, I noticed using chromes developer console that every that it iterates through every `<Item />` component it calls `handleProductRedirect` even though that Item wasn't clicked on. It does it automatically. Instead of calling that function when the div `itemBox` is clicked on, it calls it when it's rendered. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are calling the `handleProductRedirect` on every render for each item. Instead of that, you need send the callback in the `onClick` prop, something like this:

```
class Item extends Component{
  onClickItem = () => { // <=== Defines the callback and bind it to the instance
    const { element } = this.props;
    this.props.handleProductRedirect(element['productNumber']);
  };

  render(){
    var element = this.props.element;
    return (
        <div id="itemBox" onClick={this.onClickItem}>
            <h3>{elementTitle.slice(0, 85)}</h3>
            <p>{element.Manufacturer}</p>
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

This way you are not calling the callback on every render, but when the user actually clicks element.

Also, don't forget to define the `propTypes` on your components, it really helps to catch issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick is calling the function here:

```
onClick={this.props.handleProductRedirect(element['productNumber'])}>
```

Instead you should return a function that calls it with the argument. You can do that by making an arrow function like this:

```
onClick={() => this.props.handleProductRedirect(element['productNumber'])}>
```

But the best way to do it is to extract it into a class method (so that you don't get unnecessary re-renders):

```
class Item extends Component {
  clickProduct = () => {
    this.props.handleProductRedirect(this.props.element['productNumber']);
  }

  render() {
    var element = this.props.element;
    return (
      <div id="itemBox" onClick={this.clickProduct}>
        <h3>{elementTitle.slice(0, 85)}</h3>
        <p>{element.Manufacturer}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```